# Raspberry Pi Connecting to 8 calculator screens

Tags: pi-3, hardware, screen

First of all I want to say that I am a complete noob with hardware so sorry if this question is stupid.

What I want to do:

I am designing a board game, in that game I want to have a raspberry pi handle a timer and each players data (HP value, Shield value, Damage taken) with some calculation options.

Is it possible to hook up the Raspberry Pi to 8 different (calculator) screens and show different data on all of those?

What do I need to achieve this? How do I connect those?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have a great day! :D

Comment: Hello and welcome – You can not connect 8 screens to one raspberry pi. Check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171285) out.

Comment: If by "calculator screen" you mean segmented LCD outputs like on many/most calculators that come in sizes such as "16x2" (2 rows of 16 characters each), these are very cheap and connect to GPIOs.  They don't count as "screens" in the sense of M. Rostami's comment.  It may well be possible to connect 8 or more of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "calculator screen" you mean segmented LCD outputs like on many/most calculators that come in sizes such as "16x2" (2 rows of 16 characters each), these are cheap and widely available, for example:

[image]

From: https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi

An issue with this, however, is that it requires 6 GPIOs, so you could not connect eight of them that way.  However, you should be able to find them with I2C backpack chips (or you may have to buy the backpacks separately):

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/control-a-raspberry-pi-hd44780-lcd-display-via-i2c/

In order for this to work with 8 such displays, they all need to have a unique address on the I2C bus.  Many devices have an address hardcoded, making it awkward to use more than one of the same kind on the same bus. However, often they will have switches/pins used to set the address.  If you can find a device with 8+ possible addresses you are all set.  If you can find one that will do 4 you may be able to configure an additional I2C bus on the Pi breakout.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, now that I know that it should be possible, I am going to look for someone to help me out and build it!